KivyMD - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
I just installed KivyMD. When I try to run a simple code from "Getting Started" on kivymd page.
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return MDLabel(text="Hello, World", halign="center")


MainApp().run()

But I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\kivymd\MDvirt\firsproject.py", line 2, in <module>
     from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
   File "C:\kivymd\MDvirt\Lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\label\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
     from .label import MDIcon, MDLabel  # NOQA F401
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\kivymd\MDvirt\Lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\label\label.py", line 595, in <module>
     with open(
          ^^^^^
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\kivymd\\MDvirt\\Lib\\site-packages\\kivymd\\uix\\label\\label.kv'

Any ideas why?

With kivymd 1.2.0 installed on Python 3.12.3 this is not reproducible
